# Mass dimension of Dirac spinors (QFT)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, spinors

From a dimensional analysis (with $\hbar=1=c $) of the Dirac Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}= \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi $ one obtains that the mass dimension of $\psi$ is $3/2$ (i.e. $[\mathcal{L}]=M^4 \Rightarrow [\psi]=M^{3/2})$. However, when one works with a plane wave (e.g. with positive energy), $\psi(x)=u(p)e^{-ip.x}$, then $ u(p)$ is normalized as $\bar{u}(p)u(p)= 2m$ (see e.g. Peskin & Schroeder - An introduction to QFT, eq. (3.60) and above) and thus has a mass dim. equal to $1/2$.
But how is this possible? Shouldn't it be $[\psi(x)] = [u(p)e^{-ip.x}]=[u(p)][e^{-ip.x}]=[u(p)].1=M^{3/2} $?

Comment: Hint: The fermionic creation/annihilation operators also carry mass dimension.